# Showing multiple panels of long text in iOS without memory issues?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview

We have an app that shows threaded discussions from our website. So there's an opening message, and then a variable number of reply messages, all of which we're trying to show in a single "view" on screen, that the user can scroll down. Message lengths can vary from a sentence or even just a word, all the way up to 100s of KB of text.

Each message in the conversation also will display the author name, photo, a timestamp, and other meta info.

We want every message to be completely visible. By that I mean, the user can scroll down the entire view, seeing all message text, not having to sub-scroll within each reply to read the text, nor having to click a "Read More..." link to isolate the message text in a different view.

[Apple states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) that UIViews that need to show much more than a screenful of text "should consider tiling" the content, to avoid memory issues, but no additional information is provided.

From what I understand, UITextView and UIWebView both use tiling techniques to display text more efficiently and avoid these memory problems.

Are there other classes available that offer similar efficiency for the kind of use I am facing? (Either from Apple, or third parties with open source or source licensing.)

If not, it would seem that our choices would be to roll our own, or figure out a way to use UIWebView. If we go with UIWebView, what are the downsides we may encounter?

If your recommendation is to roll our own, can you provide any advice as to where to start? We've never created our own UIView subclass, being fairly new to iOS development.

Comment: Why not use a table view? Only the cells visible on screen will be using the memory intensive images, and the cells get reused.

Comment: Would this solve the underlying problem we are having, though? Right now each reply message in our discussion is a UIView, and often times these replies are very long, which is where the memory problems come into play. If I understand UITableView, each reply message would be in a UITableViewCell, which is a subclass of UIView. Wouldn't we therefore have the same issue... that the UIView holding the message is essentially too long?

Comment: I don't think 100's of kilobytes should be too long for one cell. Do you actually know that you have memory problems?

Comment: @rdelmar Yeah, the team building this is using UIViews now for each message, and we are running into issues with memory use from this, resulting in the app crashing. One of the proposed solutions is to go to a UIWebView. I'm leery of this after reading about Facebook's experience, and witnessing it first hand with Apple's own App Store app...

Comment: UITableView will solve your memory problems if the rest of the code is good quality, it won't solve your memory problems if other parts of your code generates memory leaks.

Comment: Does UITableView allow you to have complex UIViews as the contents of the tableviewcells?

Comment: Yes, you can customize the cells to look like you want. The simplest way to do this is to design the cell in the storyboard or xib, and create a custom class for that cell so you can hook up any subviews to IBOutlets.

Comment: The advantage of using UITableView (in terms of memory consumption) is that this component will reuse your cell so that only 7-8 cell are actually allocated. So if correctly implemented you can have thousands of cells and no memory issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turns out the app is already using UITableView for this design, and memory is still an issue.